# How to know the Feed url from the domain?

Tags: php, javascript, rss, feed

On http://simplepie.org/demo/, if you insert mashable.com it automatically fetches the Feed URL.

How is it done?

Comment: .. Edited your question to change the URL. Hope it is okay.

Answer (score 5):

You go into the page source and search for the following element:

For a RSS feed:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="`your feed address`" />
```

For an Atom feed:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="`your feed address`" />
```

That is probably the simplest (easy to parse) and most reliable (it was explicitly declared as a feed equivalent of the page) way to get the feed address.

Comment: To be exact:

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/simplepie" />

Comment: That is clearly a simple way to look for an RSS feed but it isn't the only way, nor does it accurately describe the way SimplePie locates feeds, as asked in the question.  The SimplePie library is much more flexible in it's approach.

Comment: @Sugerman: I had understood that "How is it done?" was a way of phrasing "How could someone do it?" - and that simplepie.org was simply an example of a website/script that exhibited such functionality. (For example, I could have given the same reply if instead of speaking of simplepie, xRobot had asked about the Google Reader "Add feed" box.) Of course, if the question is interpreted as "How does simplepie.org deduce a feed URL from a domain?" then your answer is the only valid one.

Answer (score 4):

Download the source code and open `simplepie.inc` in the base directory.  It contains a class called `SimplePie_Locator` with methods for locating Feeds within the HTML returned by a website.

Looking at the methods `get_links()` and `extension()` it seems it only works for feeds (`html`, `link` or `area`) that  end in one of `('.rss', '.rdf', '.atom', '.xml')`

Answer (score 0):

i believe, it scans all links ( tags) on specified url for rss-format response which is simple to parse and to output as html.

Comment: I tried stackoverflow and the result is "no feed found'. Every question in SO has a feed url. If it scans all links then So will have 1,041,299 feed URLs ;-)

Comment: I believe that heximal was writing about the `<link />` elements, not the `<a>` anchor elements.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to utilise the google api to do a search for:

```
filetype:xml site:whatever.com
```

And return the first result....

Comment: If you try to do that for mashable.com, you get the `sitemap.xml`.

Comment: Sure- but leveraging off googles search capabilities you could buuild a pretty sophisticated scraper, i.e. filetype:xml site:whatever.com -sitemap.....